# React fetch post, page refreshing and becomes a GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, post, get

I have a login page in my REACT website sending a POST request with fetch, but every time the request is submitted for some reason it refreshes the page and send it as a GET request, here's the method on my login page:

```
    onSubmitSignIn = () => {
        fetch("http://192.168.56.1:8560/signin", {
            type: 'POST', 
            headers: {'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: this.state.signinEmail, 
                password: this.state.signinPassword, 
            }),
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data ==='success'){
    
            }
        })
          
    }
```

the server side signing page is as follows:

```
app.post('/signin', (req, res) => {

    if (req.body.email === database.users[0].email && req.body.password === database.users[0].password){
        res.json("success"); 
    }else{
        res.status(404).json("Error loggingin");
    }
})
```

It's working fine with Postman, the server seems to be ok.

I have tried changing HTTP to https even though my server is HTTP just in case.
Tried restarting both servers, tried changing to fetch to axios but nothing seems to be working.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `type: 'POST', ` shouldn't this be `method: 'POST',`?

Answer (score 0):

```
onSubmitSignIn = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault() // <= You Need this

        fetch("http://192.168.56.1:8560/signin", {
            type: 'POST', 
            headers: {'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: this.state.signinEmail, 
                password: this.state.signinPassword, 
            }),
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data ==='success'){
    
            }
        })    
    }
```

Comment: just changed it, but unfortunately it

Comment: Still the same issue. could it have anything to do with the browser's config? or maybe with the development server? I haven't changed any configurations on the react development server, but I'm still wondering if it could be any issues not with my code but on the deployment.

Comment: Ok my friend. I will tell you another way

Answer (score 0):

Create-React-App Proxying API Requests in Development -- `src/setupProxy.js`

People often serve the front-end React app from the same host and port as their backend implementation.

Such setup is not required. However, if you do have a setup like this, it is convenient to write requests like `fetch('/api/todos')` without worrying about redirecting them to another host or port during development.

To tell the development server to proxy any unknown requests to your API server in development, add a `proxy` field to your `package.json`, for example:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8560",
```

Configuring the Proxy Manually
First, install `http-proxy-middleware` using npm or Yarn:

```
$ npm install http-proxy-middleware --save
$ # or
$ yarn add http-proxy-middleware
```

Next, create `src/setupProxy.js` and place the following contents in it:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:8560',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

### API:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Answer (score 0):

I'm just replying in case anybody has got the same issue as I was having, after a couple of sleepless nights digging through my code, I figure the template for my login page was taken from a "tachyon" template, what I missed, somewhere in my version control, was a "form" that was actually supposed to be turned into a "div", after going through this question here [why-the-post-request-becomes-a-get-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41758371/why-the-post-request-becomes-a-get-request) it hit me, basically, if you happen to be taking the information from inside of a "form" and this form does not have a method post, it will automatically turn the API request into a GET request and fill up the URL with the information.

So that is sorted. Now let us tackle the rest of the bugs.